# SSRS 2012 and SharePoint 2010 Standard

Tags: ssrs, sharepoint

Is it possible to use Report Builder Model, Report Builder Report, Report Data Sources with a Sharepoint **Standard** 2010 edition?

Answer (score 0):

The three of them are available with SharePoint standard. Just need to activate the content types (after a restart of SP services).